# Finding Network Drive from UNC Path

Tags: c#, hyperlink, copy, clipboard

I created a button that grabs the text contents of the `Clipboard` class, checks if it's a folder path and creates a hyperlink out of it. The user will probably just copy the path from the explorer window. The problem I have, which seems to be the opposite of a lot of questions I found, is that I want the drive path (T:\Natzely) instead of the UNC path (\SEOMAFIL02\Trash\Natzely).

When I ctrl+v the copied path into either Word, Notepad or Outlook it gets copied as drive path, but when I copy it to Chrome's address bar or try to retrieve it from the `Clipboard` class it gets copied as the UNC path. How does Microsoft deal with this?

My drive letters stay pretty much static, so I don't have to worry about the T drive not being the Trash drive in the future.

**EDIT**

Here is the code

```
object clipboardText = Clipboard.GetText();
if(!Directory.Exists(clipboardText.ToString()))
{
    //Show error message
}

doc = GetDoc(); //Get document to add the hyperlink to
sel = doc.Selection;
range = sel.Range;
hyperlinks = sel.Hyperlinks;
hyperlinks.Add(range, ref clipboardText);
```

**EDIT Numero Dos**

It seems to be more of an issue with `Hyperlinks.Add` than the clipboard. If I add a space before the clipboard text `object clipboardText = " " + Clipboard.GetText()` it seems to correct the issue, the hyperlink will now have and extra space before but the link still works.

Comment: What do you mean by "copy it to chrome" ? Do you mean you paste the path to Chrome's address bar, or... ?

Comment: I'm testing this on my side, and the Clipboard content is as-is, meaning when it's a UNC, I get a UNC, when it's a drive letter path, then I get a drive letter path. Please post your code.

Comment: Yes, Chrome's address bar. I've added some code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you see this question from Microsoft?
[Translate UNC path to local mounted driveletter.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/020b8afc-b43b-4cf0-b12f-69cc443f9edf/translate-unc-path-to-local-mounted-driveletter)

Seems like there are two ways. The first way is to get the value from the registry:

```
string UNCtoMappedDrive(string uncPath)
{
    Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey rootKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("network");

    foreach (string subKey in rootKey.GetSubKeyNames())
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey mappedDriveKey = rootKey.OpenSubKey(subKey);

        if (string.Compare((string)mappedDriveKey.GetValue("RemotePath", ""), uncPath, true) == 0)
            return subKey.ToUpperInvariant() + @":\";
    }

    return uncPath;
}
```

The other way is with System.Management. The example is large, but here's the core of it:

```
private void LoadDrives()
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT RemoteName, LocalName FROM Win32_NetworkConnection");
    List<UncToDrive> drives = new List<UncToDrive>();
    foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get())
    {
        object localObj = obj["LocalName"];
        if (!Object.Equals(localObj, null))
            drives.Add(new UncToDrive(obj["RemoteName"].ToString(), localObj.ToString()));
    }
}
```

They search for all paths with the drive (LocalName) and without (RemoteName), then save them in a list for later lookup.